# Need help solving inequality with trigonometric terms

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

$$ \frac{\cos x}{2\sin\frac\pi2 - \sin x} > 0 $$

This is the question I need help solving. The first thing I did was turn $2\sin\frac\pi2$ into 2(1) but I'm not sure how to simplify it further.

Answer (score 4):

Because $2-\sin x \in [1,3]$, this means that the denominator is always positive. So the only thing you have to worry about is the numerator. So, if
$$
\frac{a}{b} >0
$$
and $b>0$, what can you conclude about the numerator?